# Why did the vowel in "Christ" become long in moving from Old English to Middle English?

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change, vowels, old-english, middle-english

I have read the following question and all the answers, and they do not answer my question, so it is not a duplicate:

[Why are the vowels in Christ and Christmas different? (and other strange diphthong behaviour)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329151/why-are-the-vowels-in-christ-and-christmas-different-and-other-strange-diphtho)

---

From [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Christ):

> From Middle English [Crist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Crist#Middle_English), from Old English [Crist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Crist#Old_English)

- Middle English Crist:  **/kriːst/**, /krist/
- Old English: **/krist/**

The vowel in Old English was a short vowel **/i/** but in Middle English, it became **/i:/**.

I read [**Homorganic Lengthening** in this excellent answer by Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/202360/387044) according to which vowels were lengthened before /mb nd ld rd ŋg/, but **/st/ is voiceless**.

Were vowels also lengthened before voiceless pairs? Why is this change in "christ"?

Comment: See also: https://www.quora.com/Why-did-the-vowel-in-the-word-Christ-change-in-Middle-English-It-was-krist-in-OldEn-but-kri-St-in-Middle-English-Why

Comment: The title-question looks near-identical; are you saying that you find the answer/s there inadequate? If so, it is correct procedure to add a bonus say at the original. // Note that saying that 'this is an example of homorganic lengthening' say doesn't really address the issue of **why** such changes have taken place, merely that they were wholesale.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My bad. I have clarified it now. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the correction below. I have always been writing "old" and "middle" with small initial letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long and short vowels were written the same way in Old English (macrons, the lines marking long vowels, are a modern convention). Given the current pronunciation of *Christ*, I’d guess it had a long and not a short vowel in Old English. But I’m not sure.  If it did have a long vowel, the reason might be because Latin [*Chrīstus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11353/what-is-the-evidence-for-a-long-vowel-in-%CF%87%CF%81%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%82-anointed-and-latin-christus) apparently had a long vowel.

The [Ormulum](https://archive.org/details/ormulumwithnotes01whituoft/page/n101/mode/2up) (early Middle English) uses the spelling *Crist* (where the non-doubled s indicates a long i) alongside *Crisstene* and *Crisstenndom*.

If the word really did have a short vowel in Old English, French influence could possibly be a reason for the pronunciation with a long vowel in Middle English. Monosyllabic words ending in /st/ taken from French, like *coast, toast, feast,* fairly often have long vowels for some reason.

---

I looked at the Oxford English Dictionary entry for *Christ,* and it says the length of the vowel in Old English is "uncertain".

---

It isn't a case of homorganic lengthening of the type found in *child*: that lengthening process was an early sound change that only regularly applied before consonant clusters ending in a voiced consonant, not ones like /st/ ending in a voiceless consonant.

Comment: Given the fact that Old and Middle English were both collections of variegated dialects, it's almost certain that it was a short vowel sometimes and a long vowel sometimes, and we've reified those changes by changing the pronunciations in the standard. Why one or the other won out in individual words is often a lost story.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You seem to know much about old and middle English, would you mind if I asked you to attempt to answer my another question I asked a few days ago? Here it is: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/557651/387044
there is already an answer but I'm not satisfied with that answer yet.